# Определение вершин использовать координат декартовой системы координат

Tags: java

У меня возникла проблема.
Есть у меня класс фигуры трапеции, и нужно реализовать методы вычисления
периметра и площади, но только с определения вершин использовать координат декартовой системы координат. Как реализовать определения вершин при помощи координат декартовой системы координат на Java

Буду рад вашей помощи.

Вот сам код

```
package javaapplication11;
import java.util.Scanner;

class trapezium {
      
}
public class JavaApplication11 {
    
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
        int a,b;
        
    }
    
}
```

Comment: `использовать координат декартовой системы координат.` т.е. вам нужно задавать X и Y

Comment: То есть сделать ввод X и Y, и тогда это будет высота ?

Comment: Вы сами понимаете, что именно вам нужно сделать?

Comment: Координаты X и Y нужно задавать для каждой вершины. У трапеции их четыре.

Comment: Все понял.  Спасибо.